# Select Objects by position after rigid body physics in blender 2.9

Tags: blender, rigid-bodies

I am using the rigid body physics option in blender to drop balls (meshes) into a box. Some of the balls miss the box entirely and fall past the box. I want to be able to select just the balls which fall into the box an export them individually to an .stl file, with their global position (after settling in the box).

I think I know how to export the files, but am having trouble on how to select the mesh objects based on their position at a given frame. I am planning to use this for multiple instances, and hence I need help with a way of doing this via scripting using python.

Note: The balls are dropped from a random height and when I select the object, the z position it shows still looks like its initial starting position.

Im new to blender, so any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score -1):

I did find this elsewhere, you need to use .matrix_world.translation rather than .location to select objects via their locations at a given frame

Comment: you should make sure you properly conduct research before posting a question on stack overflow

Comment: I spent 4 hours searching for a solution to no avail, significant research was put into this problem